# Using XPath to get text of paragraph with links inside

Tags: html, xpath

I'm parsing HTML page with XPath and want to grab whole text of some specific paragraph, including text of links.

For example I have following paragraph:

```
<p class="main-content">
    This is sample paragraph with <a href="http://google.com">link</a> inside.
</p>
```

I need to get following text as result: "This is sample paragraph with link inside", however applying `"//p[@class'main-content']/text()"` gives me only "This is sample paragraph with  inside".

Could you please assist? Thanks.

Comment: The code is broken – you don't close the `href` attribute quotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the whole text content of a node, use the [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256133.aspx) function:

```
string(//p[@class="main-content"])
```

Note that this gets a string value. If you want text nodes (as returned by `text()`), you can do this. You need to search at all depths:

```
//p[@class="main-content"]//text()
```

This returns three text nodes: `This is sample paragraph with`, `link` and `inside.`