# Scrape paragraph with href inside

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, lxml

This is the html:

```
<p class="myParagraph">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel justo
  <a href="http://google.it" class="small-link" target="_blank">
    <span class="tco-ellipsis"></span>
    <span class="invisible">https://</span>
    <span class="js-display-url">google.it</span>
    <span class="invisible">lpage/events/?ref=page_internal&amp;mt_nav=0&amp;locale2=it_IT</span>
    <span class="tco-ellipsis">
      <span class="invisible">&nbsp;</span>…
    </span>
  </a> ornare, suscipit nisl eget, aliquam augue. Aenean quis pretium
</p>
```

If i use `tree.xpath('//p/text()')` it only returns me

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel justo*

instead of

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel justo ornare, suscipit nisl eget, aliquam augue. Aenean quis pretium*

I also tried `tree.xpath('string(//p)')` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8066566/9812699)
How can i take both complete paragraph and href? Not every time there's a `a` element inside paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xpath('//p/text()')` returns a list of strings. Join these strings to get the wanted result.

```py
from lxml import html

doc = """<p class="myParagraph">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel justo
  <a href="http://google.it" class="small-link" target="_blank">
    <span class="tco-ellipsis"></span>
    <span class="invisible">https://</span>
    <span class="js-display-url">google.it</span>
    <span class="invisible">lpage/events/?ref=page_internal&amp;mt_nav=0&amp;locale2=it_IT</span>
    <span class="tco-ellipsis">
      <span class="invisible">&nbsp;</span>…
    </span>
  </a> ornare, suscipit nisl eget, aliquam augue. Aenean quis pretium
</p>"""

root = html.fromstring(doc)
print("".join([t for t in root.xpath("//p/text()")]))
```